# XAML/UWP add drop shadow to shapes on canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, uwp, shadow

So I am rendering a variety of shapes on a Canvas, think PowerPoint. The user can CRUD shapes on the Canvas.

I would now like to add a DropShadow to a Shape.

Only, I have no idea how to actually do that. Community Toolkit does not seem to allow adding a dropshadow in Code-Behind (at least there is no docu). The other few solutions found online seem to apply ways that are either not UWP-compatible, or deprecated...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The [DropShadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.dropshadow?view=winrt-19041) class provides means of creating a configurable shadow that can be applied to a SpriteVisual or LayerVisual (subtree of Visuals). You can try to use it to add drop shadow to your shapes. First create a new DropShadow and associate it to your visual. For example:

```
Compositor compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(YourShape).Compositor;
var shadowVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
Vector2 newSize = new Vector2(0, 0);
if (YourShape is FrameworkElement element)
{
    newSize = new Vector2((float)element.ActualWidth, (float)element.ActualHeight);
}
shadowVisual.Size = newSize;

var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
dropShadow.BlurRadius = 10;
dropShadow.Opacity = 0.3f;
dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(10,10,10);
dropShadow.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;

shadowVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;

ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(YourShape, shadowVisual);
```

For more details about DropShadow, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-shadows).

Comment: Thank you. So what do I have to do when the same Shape is moved or resized...? How to I remove the existing shadow and replace it with a new one, as I assume that the API does not monitor the Shape itself...

Comment: When you move the Shape, you don't need to replace the shadow, it will move with the Shape. If you want to resize the Shape, you just need to use the above method again to re-create the shadow. It will directly cover the old shadow.

Comment: Worked nicely until I opened up the full feature set of allowing rotation of shapes... that resulted in `Access denied.  Calling ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual API is not allowed on this object at this time, as this object currently has the CenterPoint property in use.`

Comment: How did you "opened up the full feature set of allowing rotation of shapes"? When you tried to rotate the shape, it's better to use **RenderTransform** to rotate it. For example, `shape.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform()
            {
                CenterX = 300,
                CenterY = 300,
                Angle = 45 
            };`

Comment: Faywang, the feature set of my app, maybe? Working on something else today and tomorrow, will look in two days. This switch of the way I rotate the shape will require additional testing...

Comment: OK, when you test it, if you have any progress, you can update here.

Comment: Right, finally back on this topic. Sorry for the delay. Faywang, how do I deal with changes to the shape due the edits? When the user moves/resizes the shape, how do I update this shadow? Will it stay attached or do I need to do something? Also, how do I remove this shadow if the user does no longer want it? Much obliged.